# Why are these two SQL queries so different in efficiency?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, subquery, left-join

I have to use SQL for my internship and while I know the gist of it, I do not really have a background in programming nor do I know what makes codes efficient etc.

***Query #1***

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    c.[STAT], c.[EVENT], f.[STAT], f.[EVENT]
FROM
    (SELECT *
     FROM 
         (SELECT 
              *, 
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [PROCDT], [PROCTIME]) AS a
          FROM 
              TABLE) AS b
    ) AS c
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         *
     FROM 
         (SELECT 
              *, 
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [PROCDT], [PROCTIME]) AS d
          FROM 
              TABLE) AS e
         ) AS f ON c.[ID] = f.[ID] AND a = d - 1
ORDER BY 
    c.[STAT], c.[EVENT], f.[STAT], f.[EVENT]
```

***Query #2***

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    b.[STAT], b.[EVENT], d.[STAT], d.[EVENT]
FROM
    (SELECT 
         *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [PROCDT], [PROCTIME]) AS a
     FROM TABLE) AS b
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [PROCDT], [PROCTIME]) AS c
     FROM TABLE) AS d ON b.[ID] = f.[ID] AND a = c - 1
ORDER BY 
    b.[STAT], b.[EVENT], d.[STAT], d.[EVENT]
```

Queries #1 and #2 return the same result, which is expected, but query #1 has a runtime of roughly 5 seconds while query #2 has a runtime of roughly 1 minute and 35 seconds. In other words, the second query takes a good 1.5 minutes longer to run than the first and I am really curious to know why.

Comment: before running both queries include the actual execution plan : CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+M  : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-keyboard-shortcuts?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: also https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: Looks like you should be using `LEAD/LAG` instead of messing around with joins in the first place. The reason you are getting different times is because the query was recompiled, and the plan is different. Execute it in SSMS, and view the actual execution plan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to write this query uses `lead()`.  I'm pretty sure the `select distinct` is not needed, so this does what you want:

```
SELECT stat, event,
       LEAD(stat) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, ORDER BY PROCDT, PROCTIME) as next_stat,
       LEAD(event) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, ORDER BY PROCDT, PROCTIME) as next_event
FROM TABLE t
ORDER BY stat, event;
```

The two queries you have written should be the same in SQL Server.  Apparently, the extra subqueries are confusing the optimizer.  You would need to learn about execution plans to understand this better.

Comment: Thank you so much! I only require non-duplicates, so indeed I needed distinct results, but this is such a wonderful discovery - that a function like `LEAD()` exists!